# Ionic AngularJS Accordion with form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have implemented this cool accordion demo into my project :

https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz

The problem is i am wanting each accordion sub menu to hold around 10-15 form items, so checkboxes, textboxes etc. If you look at the code the text is generated dynamically so im just wondering if it is possible with this accordion to add the form items in the HTML rather than pushing dynamically, or is there an easy way to get the form items in from the controller? This is the code that generates the content :

```
 <ion-list>
        <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
          <ion-item class="item-stable"
                    ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
                    ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
              <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
            &nbsp;
            Group {{group.name}}
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                    ng-repeat="item in group.items"
                    ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
            {{item}}
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: you can add anything between the <ion-item> tags. Just replace {{item}} with what you need

Comment: I only want certain forms to show under each group is there a way to condition it?